# Jquery Autocomplete Minimum length

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Currently my autocomplete returns values after one character is entered. I simply want to increase that limit to 3 but can't get that to work. Here is my code below. As you can see I've tried adding minLength: 3 outside and also inside the source but to no avail.

```
$(function() {
   $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
     source: '${g.createLink(controller: 'template', action: 'suggestedNameValues')}'
  //minLength: 3
  });
});
```

Any ideas?

*Update*
I was missing a comma at the end of the source line.

Answer (score 3):

The default value of minLength is 1, which means the user to type at least 1 character in the search box to trigger the autocompletion.

$(function() {

```
$("#search").autocomplete(
{
    source:data,
    minLength:2
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it all right, `minLength` should be right where you've commented it. Are you sure your browser doesn't use a cached copy of script or something like that?

update: by the way, is your source link correct? I'd say this script won't run (though i'm not familiar with JS frameworks, may be it's pre-parsed before run).

Comment: Turned out to be the simplest of problems, a missing comma at the end of the source line. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your quotations in the `source`:

```
$(function () {
    $("#name").autocomplete({
        source: "${g.createLink(controller: 'template', action: 'suggestedNameValues')}",
        minLength: 3
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it turned out to be a missing comma.